# Revert back from 14.04

Tags: 12.04, 14.04

OK so vast volumes have been written on this subject for previous releases, my problems started with a Python update from an untrusted source that prevented me from updating anything ! In desperation I installed 14.04 thinking that if it did not work I would just re-instal 12 or 13 which should have Python fully updated, however I am finding it impossible to download 12.04 or 13.04 in a format I can use without an optical drive. I know enough to chose the I386 option but then I get page after page of options to chose that I know nothing about and there are no explanations or recommendations to guide me, I have Installed Ubuntu on 3 previous computers without problem but I do not speak whatever language it is you guys/gals use when talking about computers/programs. Please help me get my ASSUS EEE Atom Nettop working again, simple English for Seniors please.

Comment: "Page after page of options..." What? Where you are trying to download these images from? Have you tried simply removing Python and fixing your real issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to use a USB?

1. Use GParted (On the Software Center) to format a 2+ GB USB to FAT32
2. Use Startup Disk Creator (Already Installed) to create a bootable install disk using the 12.04 i386 ISO from the download page. 
   Grab it here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/12.04/ubuntu-12.04.5-desktop-i386.iso
3. Boot it and install!

You probably won't be able to keep your settings from 14.04, though.